# Trying to use Custom URL for opening my app, APP Delegate is not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios13

I am using custom url, minimum iOS version is 10, so I am using App delegate. I declared the required thing is

```
info.plist
```

app, is opening fine but, I am not getting callback in logs through app delegate. This function is not getting called

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool { }
```

I am testing it on iOS 16, iPhone 13.

I tried all my way to remove Application Scene Manifest from Info.Plist.
added var window: UIWindow? at top of AppDelegate. But nothing is working. My App is in background. When clicking comes to foreground. But nothing is being printed in log through this method.

Comment: I saw a couple minor things... so I'll just cover them for starters... 1- when you said "info.plist", I assume you meant "Info.plist", as you said below. 2- so if you put print statements in all the functions in the class, do you see `applicationWillEnterForeground`, (nothing for your URL handler, `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`

Comment: ...Normal behavior would see a middle entry of `application(_:open:options:)`, if you were using `print ((#function)`